# Detecting Download Status in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, dom-events, greasemonkey

Is there any way to detect whether a download has completed or is how much it has downloaded, in the context of a greasemonkey script or an extension (i.e.) how to detect if Firefox is still downloading a file or not, in a greasemonkey script or an extension?

Also please give a reliable way for using jQuery in greasemonkey.

Answer (score 2):

As Jamie Wong said, neither a Greasemonkey script (nor JavaScript) can tell the status of a file-download, client-side.

However, if your JavaScript is loading from a server you control, you can set up a system to poll the server about download status.

But, yes, you could write a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/) that can see file download status.
......

As for using jQuery in GM, 
you can see a simple Greasemonkey script, that uses jQuery, in **[this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110231/creating-a-jqueryscript-for-gm-trouble-by-rewriting-the-js-code/3115045#3115045)**.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing Javascript to have access to native functionality of your browser (such as downloading) would be a security hole, and is therefore not possible.